# d3.js - Timestamp based on year and week

Tags: d3.js

I have a column with data year&week. I would like to create a date axis based on this.

when i try to format the date, it is not working

I tried this:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%W").parse;

d3.csv("temperatures_groups_2.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d,i) {
        d.timestamp = parseDate(d.timestamp);
        alert(d.timestamp);
        d.temperature = +d.temperature;
    }
});
```

i get null when the alert executes.

If i replace the same with d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse, it works fine. It takes the month but not week no.

The csv contains data like this

timestamp,temperature
2013-01,19.5
2014-02,21.5
2015-03,20.5
2016-04,20.5
2017-05,21.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) says:

> The following directives are not yet supported for parsing:
>
> %U - week number of the year.
>
> %W - week number of the year.

Hence you can't use D3 to parse these dates. You'll have to parse the date yourself or use another library, for example [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This works since [version 3.2](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/764/) and the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) has been updated.

- `%U` - week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53].
- `%W` - week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53].

However, the format in your question won't work because the parser requires a specific date to be specified. E.g. by "%a". It would be nice to assume Sunday in the absence of a date specifier, but that's for another PR.